# Order graph by count not alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, seaborn

My data is as follows:

```
        channel    ter   Id
0       BWM        A     6
1       IND        A     15  
2       RIA        C     2
3       BWM        B     7
4       IND        B     5  
5       RIA        A     4
6       BWM        C     3
7       IND        C     33  
8       RIA        B     21
```

When I plot it:

```
sns.set(style='darkgrid')
sns.barplot(x='channel', y='Id', hue='ter', data=df, palette='Set2')
plt.show()
```

It is ordered by alphabet on the x axis, so channel is BWM->IND->RIA.
However, what I need is for it to be sorted by count (ie. Id value), so IND is first.

I tried adding `order = df['channel'].value_counts().index` inside `barplot()` but didn't help.

I Would also like to have the ability to order ter according to count as well, per channel, but don't have to if too much effort.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each channel contains multiple IDs, simply "sorted by ID" is not well-defined; you would have to specify something like the sum of IDs, the greatest ID within the group, or something else. If you want to order the bars by the greatest ID sum,

```
sns.barplot(x='channel', y='Id', hue='ter', data=df, palette='Set2', order=df.groupby('channel').Id.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).index)
```

does the job.

Comment: Thank you! this certainly worked. Is it possible to easily sort by ter within channel too? I tried adding ter to your group by but that's definitely not the right way

Comment: You can use `hue_order` for that. That is, for the fixed data set, `hue_order=['A', 'B', 'C']`, or, if you do not know the values beforehand, `hue_order=np.sort(df['ter'].unique())`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to change output. How does `np.sort(df['ter'].unique())` sort each ter by (sum) Id? I also tried same same sorting as for order with ter instead of channel but no go

Comment: I assumed you wanted the bars within each category to be sorted alphabetically. Do you want to sort them by ID within each category? That seems like it would make for a rather confusing plot.

Comment: ID here is a count of occurrences of ID actually. sorry about that